# Does Python allow lifting the GIL if multiple Polars processes are running in threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-polars, gil

I am aware that Polars is multi-threaded in Rust and bypasses the GIL. However, if I trigger multiple polars processes and use the threading library to multi-thread them would it still bypass the GIL?
For example, if I'm running this function:

```py
@run_thread
def cast_col(df, col):
   global df
   df = df.with_columns(pl.col(col).cast(pl.Int64))
```

And then calling it in multiple threads:

```py
threads_list = list()
for col in df.columns:
    threads_list.append(cast_col(df,col))

for t in threads_list:
    t.join()
```

With this code I see the threads are running concurrently bypassing the GIL but I thought Polars only bypassed GIL internally in Rust not with custom threading like this. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: If you run your app in single-threaded mode, using the tool [gil_load](https://github.com/chrisjbillington/gil_load), what percentage of the time is the GIL held? That will tell you how much speedup is possible.

Comment: Getting gil_load.init() must be called prior to any threads being started. This was on a fresh kernel. Even the git example is giving the same error

Comment: Why do you want this? Why not let polars do the work scheduling?

Comment: Because I want to run same operations on multiple subsets of data that are independent of each other and output separate columns at the same time